# Excel: Formatting Number - Shorten the Number / Delete Digits

Tags: excel, number-formatting

In Excel you can format numbers to meet specific need like currency or dates:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/number-format-codes-HP005198679.aspx

I read the online help and other recources but I don't find the solution for my problem:

I have numbers that look like:

```
2014.13
2014.14
2014.15
```

or I could make them look like

```
201413
201414
201415
```

I am looking for a number format that removes the first 4 digits so that the result looks like

```
13
14
15
```

It this even possible with number format? I know how to do it with a normal formula but I need to use  the number format.

[image]

**Update**

Thanks for the suggestions. I cannot work with cells and formulas because I use the numbers as the values for the x axes of a xy chart.

The numbers are year + kalenderweek. But I do not want to have so long numbers as tick labels in the chart I just want to show the kalenderweek. Excel offers the possibility to format the x axes values but I cannot apply normal formulas like `right()`.

Comment: No. It's a number. In my post I used the international convention. It's a normal number. I just use the German Excel version and use the German decimal convention. But thatÄs not important for teh question. But good that you ask.

Comment: Good idea. But I need the 2014 in order to get the right order. I have much more (it's the year + calender week): 2013.12 and 2014.12 for example. I need the 2013 to be able to use the numbers in an XY chart.

Comment: @ManuelKuehner I do not believe it is possible with the built-in numberformatting.  If converting the values to strings is acceptable, you could "blank out" the first five characters by formatting their font color to be the same as the interior color.  This could be done using a macro.

Comment: @ManuelKuehner Another option would be to hide the column with the full number in it, and use a formula like =MOD(A1,1)*100 or RIGHT(A1,2) in an adjacent column for "display"

Answer (score 1):

For removing first four digit you can try somthing like this:-

```
=RIGHT(CELL_VALUE,2)
```

This will give you 2 digits from right thus removing 4 digits from left.

Comment: Thanks. I need to do it with a number format not with a formula in a cell. I added a screenshot to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

Select the cells you wish to format and run this small macro:

```
Sub HideCharacters()
    Dim D As String
    D = Chr(34)
    For Each r In Selection
        r.Value = Chr(39) & r.Value
        r.NumberFormat = ";;;" & D & Right(r.Value, 2) & D
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.